# Python - Using GroupBy on Pandas DataFrame returns numbers instead of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset with over 50 columns and 30,000 rows. One of those columns is "Region" and has the following possible values ["Europe", "Americas", "Asia"]

I wanted to create a simple table which groups all the regions and counts how many instances there are.
This is the code I am using

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('Region')['Date'].count()
```

I instead get a table like this:

```
Region          Date
1,0000.00        1
10,000.00        1
10,300.00        1
134,104,360.34   1
....            ....
iA               1
iBBB-            2
null            30
```

Can someone explain to me why this happens? I tried with other columns and I get similar results. I expected the table just have 3 rows with the total count indicated on the right hand side.

Thanks

Comment: `df['Region'].value_counts()`

Comment: What does df['Region'].unique() return?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('Region').size()
```